# Image processing for thermography

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm gonna try to build an android application that uses image processing techniques to turn the smartphone camera into a thermographic one. I have no experience in the image processing context, so I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me about the development process or where to begin.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: you should try [openCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first: You can't "turn the smartphone camera into a thermographic one". At least at good "thermographic one" (even if You remove IR glass filter). You need special device (Thermal Imager like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NYWAHHM)) to do that (or connect your camera to pyrometer).

And for image processing: take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).